# Formatting input type date in vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I use bootstrap-vue, which includes an input type of date.

When I write some number, the default format is yyyyyy-mm-dd.

I want to change that format to yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use a formatter:

```
:formatter="format"
```

Declare how the value should be formatted within this function:

```
format(value, event) {
    return moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
}
```

As an example using the `momentjs` library.

Comment: formatter option works after typing all text. if I type 20190314 it returns 201903-14- .

Comment: It should not matter the format at which you type. The purpose of using a data library in the formatter is to take an arbitrary string an attempt to convert it to the proper case. If it's not proper, you should display . an error and let the user know.

Answer (score 1):

I am using moment.js

```
data:{
        startDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        endDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    }
```

HTML

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" v-model="startDate"> {{startDate}}
<input type="date" class="form-control" v-model="endDate"> {{endDate}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<input type="date" v-model="moment(mydate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')" v-on:input="mydate = moment($event.target.value).toDate()"/>
```